# php разные потоки

Tags: php, mysql, потоки-данных

Здравствуйте можете объяснить что нужно сделат, или подсказать где можно найти нормальный пример.

Задание для выполнения скриптов в разных потоках:
Что нужно сделать

- Mysql БД из 5-и таблиц (названия таблиц произвольные). Колонки: `ID`, `DATE_TIME_CHANGE`, `COMM`
- 5 php произвольных скриптов. Каждый делает запрос к своей таблице, выбирает записи все записи и делает `update DATE_TIME_CHANGE` на текущее дату-время
- Вызвать выполнение этих скриптов в отдельных потоках
- (каждую таблицу заполнить произвольными данными в количестве 10000 строк в каждой таблице)

Учесть, что в произвольны момент времени сторонним скриптом может произойти update одной из таблиц поля `DATE_TIME_CHANGE` и может произойти `deadlock` транзакций. Нужно предотвратить такую ситуацию.

Comment: Если скрипт пишет только в свою таблицу, то ни о каком deadlock речи быть не может.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov в задании и не написано, что именно один из этих 5 скриптов это может сделать. Написано `сторонним скриптом`. @TigranMkrtchyan - [http://www.php.su/mysql/manual/?page=LOCK_TABLES]

Comment: Используйте транзакции при записи в базу.
То есть каждый скрипт сначала читает, что ему нужно, затем открывает транзакцию, записывает и закрывает транзакцию. Ну и таблицы желательно иметь в InnoDB.

Comment: Ну, допустим, вы написали одного супервизора, который запускает 5 ваших скриптов, которые хотят накосячить вам в базу, самое банальное решение, это проверить уровень изоляции транзакций (легко гуглится и по дефолту будет repeatableRead (он подойдет, ну или минимум, ReadCommited)) и обернуть ваши запросы, те, что UPDATE в транзакции (как уже написал @ВикторКарев , таблицы должны быть с транзакционным движком, отлично впишется InnoDB).